"Your computer does not have enough free memory to automatically analyze the problem and send a report to the developers"
I have been receiving this after the computer woke up from sleep. Here is a screenshot
Problem in chrome
I tried uninstalling chrome but it still shows this error every few minutes.
I looked as best I could but haven't got a clue.
Post of memory usage
$ free -m
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15937        2808       12811          97         677       13129
Swap:           4095           0        4095

$ top -n1 -o %MEM

top - 09:49:51 up 8 min,  1 user,  load average: 2.29, 1.82, 0.95
Tasks: 419 total,   1 running, 418 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.0 us,  2.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 97.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st 
MiB Mem :  15937.9 total,  12783.2 free,   2837.1 used,    683.8 buff/cache     
MiB Swap:   4096.0 total,   4096.0 free,      0.0 used.  13100.7 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND  
   3089 -------+  20   0 4525492 239628  85616 S   0.0   1.5   0:14.04 gnome-s+ 
   4324 -------+  20   0   32.7g 217724 143524 S   0.0   1.3   0:21.21 chrome   
   5430 -------+  20   0 1155.9g 172192  88824 S   0.0   1.1   0:04.23 chrome   
   5484 -------+  20   0 1155.9g 140696  91076 S   0.0   0.9   0:01.59 chrome   
   4414 -------+  20   0   32.7g 113044  67336 S   0.0   0.7   0:07.74 chrome   
   5550 -------+  20   0 1155.9g  98032  75776 S   0.0   0.6   0:00.16 chrome   
   5472 -------+  20   0 1155.9g  90588  70912 S   0.0   0.6   0:00.11 chrome   
   5495 -------+  20   0 1157.7g  85940  64000 S   0.0   0.5   0:00.08 chrome   
   4417 -------+  20   0   32.4g  81072  61732 S   0.0   0.5   0:03.95 chrome   
   4383 -------+  20   0  966912  70640  48080 S   0.0   0.4   0:00.83 mutter-+ 
   5102 -------+  20   0   32.4g  65152  52096 S   0.0   0.4   0:00.04 chrome   
   5563 -------+  20   0 1155.9g  57972  41856 S   0.0   0.4   0:00.01 chrome   
   3699 -------+  20   0 3144452  56388  40888 S   0.0   0.3   0:00.98 gjs      
   4347 -------+  20   0  351260  51116  30484 S   0.0   0.3   0:02.27 Xwayland 
   4353 -------+  20   0  689472  49640  35436 S   0.0   0.3   0:00.19 gsd-xse+ 
   3293 -------+  20   0  956608  47824  34640 S   0.0   0.3   0:00.25 evoluti+ 
   4342 -------+  20   0   32.4g  43520  31232 S   0.0   0.3   0:00.02 chrome  


Did you also remove ~/.config/google-chrome ?

rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome doesn't seem to help :(

Then I suggest you restart and see if it happens again, if it does search for google-Chrome-stable in your hard drive.

Did you figure this out @ZhongyuanFan ? It has just started happening to me.  Even after a reboot and without (intentionally) starting Chrome.

@baldmark sorry no... I switched back to win11 and use WSL2

I realize OP moved on, but I had the same issue and was able to resolve it by removing the .crash file for Chrome. The command on my system was as follows:
rm /var/crash/_opt_google_chrome_chrome.1000.crash

After removing the file, the crash notifications stopped popping up on my machine.
